# Remove white spaces on p:calendar

Tags: jsf, primefaces, calendar

I am currently using PrimeFaces 5.2. I need to format the datetime string like the pattern inside the tag of p:calendar but it still adds space between the date and time.

this is the code snippet inside my .xhtml file

```
<p:calendar placeholder="example: 20152008191300"
            id="datetime"
            value="#{parameter.value}"
            pattern="yyyyMMddhhmmss"
            styleClass="dateTimeField"/>
```

then when I selected the time and date this is the output inside the textbox **20150820 121100**

Can someone help me remove the auto inserted space?

Answer (score 0):

The field "hour" in the pattern of Primefaces calendar is represented by a capital  `H`, you are using lowercase `h`: http://primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/calendar.xhtml

My best guess is, that this could somehow create this issue.